# how to check if a class has an operator []?

Tags: c++11, c++17, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I'm trying to check if `operator []` overloaded in some class. There is my code:

```
template <class T, class = void>
struct has_operator : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct has_operator < T,
            std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>[](int i))>> :
            std::true_type {};
```

But it doesn't work actualy.

I'm trying to write like code witch cheking if class has `operator ()`

here it's :

```
template <typename T,class=void>
struct callable_without_args: std::false_type{};

template <typename T>
struct callable_without_args<T
          ,std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>()())>>
  :std::true_type{};
```

---

Ok, This code compiles, but how to do the verification exactly in main?:

```
template <class T, class = void>
struct has_operator : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct has_operator < T,
            std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>()[0])>> :
            std::true_type {};
```

---

I did it!

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>


template <class T, class = void>
struct has_operator : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct has_operator < T,
            std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>()[0])>> :
            std::true_type {};


struct T {
    int* arr;
    T(int a) {
        arr = new int[a];
    }
    const int& operator [] (int i) {
        return arr[i];
    }
};

int main() {
    bool test = has_operator<T>::value;

    test == true ? std::cout << "yes" : std::cout << "no";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not completely clear what do you exactly want but... the following `decltype()` is wrong

```
// ---------------------VVVVVVVVV   Wrong
decltype(std::declval<T>[](int i))
```

`std::declval()` is a (declared only) function, that doesn't receive arguments.

That is: you have to "call" it, adding "`()`" after "`<T>`".

I suppose you can try with something as

```
// .....................VV  call std::declval   
decltype(std::declval<T>()[0])
// .......................^^^  and invoke operator [] over the retuned object
```

This should works when the `operator[]` of the class `T` accept a integer value.

If `operator[]` doesn't accept a integer value (by example: a `std::map` with a key incompatible with `int`) but want a value of another type, say type `U`, you can try with another `std::declval()`

```
// ........................VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV   U value
decltype(std::declval<T>()[std::declval<U>()])
```

Comment: @КириллВахрамян - you should show us a minimal but complete and compilable example; otherwise we can show some errors but it's difficult to propose a working solution.